# number of cell returned in uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

If we return 100 in numberOfRowsInSection like

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     return 100;
 }
```

then how many cells will be created at a time in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how many times the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method would be called, the answer is it would be called as much cells are visible for the moment. When you scroll, it would be called for each new cell which is about to be displayed. How does it knows how many cells are visible right now? The `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called for each cell to calculate the contentSize of the table view.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it wont allocate all the 100 cells. Instead only those which will be visible at the moment. As we are using `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];`, the cells are reused for memory handling.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

just returns the total number of cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

this method will be called each time you scroll a table view.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your cell type. If you set dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, then it initializes only what you see on the screen and when you are scrolling it will scroll down to the amount of rows you set in the method above.

Answer (score 0):

It will allocate all 100 `Cells` but visible at a time only the `Cells` which will be fixed as per

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

height of the `Cell` and  width of the `UITableView` `Frame`

Answer (score 0):

The number of cell return its base on `UITableView` height. means it return number of cell display at first time. `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method call for only visible cell it is not call for invisible cell of `UITableView`. if you scroll then `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` reuse previous invisible cell rather then cerate new one.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @pbibergal, if you are used dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier and put a condition like below then at a time approximately nine(9) cell created at a time (number of cell is depend on tableview height). otherwise 100 cell created by system at a time.

```
TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[MainCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

if you used above code then at a time limited cell created at a time (nine cell) other wise 100 cell created at a time and it was affected in memory.